# how to send image to the server using bitmap in android

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I want to send image to the server as soon as the camera captures new image or any image file added to the gallery using the ContentObserver my code is running in service I registered the ContentObserver on the service onCrate method every thing is working fine i am trying to compress he image to base 64 andI want to send this converted imgae to the server but the problem is when i capture image from camera after this line

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

my code does't proceed so my image is not transferred because those line of code was not executed 
here is the code

```
public class GallreyObserver extends  ContentObserver{
    public GallreyObserver(Context c,Handler handler) {
            super(handler);
            this.c=c;

        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onChange(selfChange);
            GallreyLogsDetail(c);
            Log.d("onChanged", "Change in logs");
        }
    private void GallreyLogsDetail(Context con)
        {
     Cursor cur = con.getContentResolver().query(images, projection, null, null, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN+ " DESC");
              gallreyData= new ArrayList<GallreyLogsInfo>();

                    int datacolumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);   

                    while(cur.moveToNext())
                    {
                        // Get the field values
                        String imagePath=cur.getString(datacolumn);

                        GallreyLogsInfo logs=new GallreyLogsInfo();
                        logs.setImgPath(imagePath);
                        gallreyData.add(logs);
    new rest().execute(new String[] {SERVICE_URL});
    }
```

AsyncTask is the inner class of GallreyObserver

```
    private class rest extends AsyncTask <String, Void, String>
        {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... urIs) {
                String response="";
                 Log.d("do", "doInBackground");
                for(String urI: urIs)
                {
                    HttpPost httppost= new HttpPost(urI);
    //              httppost.setHeader("content-type", "MULTIPART_FORM_DATA");
                    httppost.setHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data");
                    httppost.setHeader("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    //              httpParameters.setLongParameter("id", 1L);
                    int timeOutConnection=3000;
                    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,timeOutConnection);
                    int timeoutsocket=5000;
                    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters,timeoutsocket);
                    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    client.setParams(httpParameters);

                    for(int i=0;i< gallreyData.size();i++)
                    {
Log.d("list", "forr loop");
                        GallreyLogsInfo gl =gallreyData.get(i);
                        String gimagePath=gl.getImgPath();
Log.i("Listing Images","\n data:" +"" + gimagePath+ ");
 Log.d("bitmap", "before bitmap");
                      Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(gimagePath);
                      Log.d("ByteArrayOutputStream", "before ByteArrayOutputStream");
                      ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                      Log.d("compress", "before compress");
                  boolean s;
                 s= bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                 Log.d("s", ""+s); 
                     Log.d("recycle", "before recycle");
                      bitmap.recycle();
                      bitmap = null;

                      Log.d("byte", "before byte");
                      byte[] byteArray=stream.toByteArray();
                      // Byte code array to Base64 String
                         String sendImg=Base64.encodeToString(byteArray,Base64.DEFAULT);
                         Log.d("send",""+ ""+sendImg);

                     List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
Log.d("NameValuePair", "online");


                             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image path", gimagePath));

                             Log.d("going", "server");
                             httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


                             HttpResponse execute =client.execute(httppost);    
                    Log.d("server", "sent");

    }
    return null;
    }}
```

please help me i am unable to detect the problem there was no errors but my code was not executing in the flow 
thanks in advance

here is the logcat

```
05-28 12:18:24.941: D/do(25504): doInBackground
05-28 12:18:24.941: D/onChanged(25504): Change in logs
05-28 12:18:25.187: D/onChanged(25504): Change in logs
05-28 12:18:25.652: D/list(25504): forr loop
05-28 12:18:25.675: I/Listing Images(25504):  data:/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20140528_121821.jpg 
05-28 12:18:25.675: D/bitmap(25504): before bitmap
05-28 12:18:25.847: D/dalvikvm(25504): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 77K, 3% free 8034K/8259K, paused 42ms, total 47ms
05-28 12:18:26.859: I/dalvikvm-heap(25504): Grow heap (frag case) to 26.643MB for 19660816-byte allocation
05-28 12:18:26.929: D/dalvikvm(25504): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3K, 2% free 27230K/27527K, paused 11ms+4ms, total 67ms
```

Comment: Why did you comment: **bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);** ? You are using an empty ByteArrayOutputStream and converting it toByteArray();

Comment: sorry mistakenly i added the coment here now i edited my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't figure out the error without the error log, but it seems that you have a problem when converting the bitmap.

Try this class that converts image to base64

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Base64;

public class ConvertImageToBase64 {
public static String convert(String path){
InputStream inputStream = null;
try {
    inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);

byte[] bytes;
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
int bytesRead;
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
bytes = output.toByteArray();
String encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
return TextUtils.htmlEncode(encodedString);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {

    e1.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
    try {
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   }
return null;
}
}
```

It works fine; try to use it. I hope it helps you.

If you want to use your code please add the log output, and maybe it will help me on that.

Comment: i added the logcat i hope it helps

Comment: thanks its working but i have some problem when i transfer the base 64 string to the server and convert it into original image it's orientation changes i can' understand the reason any help would be appreciated